# Converting QString to utf16 hex representation for non ascii characters

Tags: string, qt, unicode, hex, ascii

I am going to convert a QString to its hex representation, everything works fine, until I put some special characters like '€':

```
QString l_str = "How are you";
qDebug() << "hex:     " << l_str.toUtf8().toHex();
qDebug() << "readable:" << l_str.toUtf8();
```

prints out:

> hex:      "486f772061726520796f753f"
>
> readable: "How are you?"

And so it easy to convert back the hex values to ascii, being just two values (48 = H etc.) the hex representation of an ascii char it is enough to iterate and convert every two chars.

If I set l_str = "H€w ar€ you?", and the hex € sign in utf8 is "e282ac" which are 6 values, the result is as following:

> hex:      "48**e282ac**77206172e282ac20796f753f"

but how can I get it back to a readable string?

It would be better having a conversion which results in an utf16 string:

> hex:   "0048006F20AC00200061007220AC00200079006F0075003F"

Consider that the "Ho€ ar€ you" string is created at runtime (so no QStringLiteral available), and I cannot use the *auto* keyword.

Comment: What do you mean with "get it back to a readable string" exactly? How do you read the string?

Comment: I read "ho€ ar€ you" from a web server, then I have to convert it to utf16 hex array, send it to a device where I have to convert it back to "ho€ ar€ you".

Comment: And which one of these steps is failing?

Comment: the stamps ain't a problem, I just can't get back the original string from the hex = 48e282ac77206172e282ac20796f753f

Comment: A web server delivers **bytes**, where the `Content-Type` header specifies the **byte** encoding.  So, if you receive an HTTP body with something like `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`, then you would know the bytes are UTF-8 and can decode them to a `QString` using [`QString::fromUtf8()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromUtf8). Once you have a `QString`, you get a UTF-16 array from it using [`QString::utf16()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#utf16). To decode UTF-16 back to `QString`, you can use [`QString::fromUtf16()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromUtf16).

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the string to utf8/16, and then convert the buffer that holds that into hexadecimal representation. These steps can be followed in reverse order to go from hex to utf8/16 to a string.

The `toUtf16Hex` function prepends a byte order mark so that both little- and big-endian hosts can correctly decode the Utf16 representation.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/str-to-utf-38831190
#include <QtCore>

QByteArray toUtf8Hex(const QString & str) {
   return str.toUtf8().toHex();
}
QString fromUtf8Hex(const QByteArray & hex) {
   return QString::fromUtf8(QByteArray::fromHex(hex));
}

QByteArray toUtf16Hex(QString str) {
   str.prepend(QChar::ByteOrderMark);
   // It is OK to use `fromRawData` since toHex copies it.
   return QByteArray::fromRawData(
            reinterpret_cast<const char*>(str.constData()), (str.size()+1)*2).toHex();
}
QString fromUtf16Hex(const QByteArray & hex) {
   const QByteArray utf16 = QByteArray::fromHex(hex);
   return QString::fromUtf16(reinterpret_cast<const quint16*>(utf16.data()));
}

int main() {
   const QString str = QStringLiteral("H€w ar€ you?");

   // To Utf8 and back
   const QByteArray hex8 = toUtf8Hex(str);
   Q_ASSERT(fromUtf8Hex(hex8) == str);

   // To Utf16 and back
   const QByteArray hex16 = toUtf16Hex(str);
   Q_ASSERT(fromUtf16Hex(hex16) == str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a hackish but working solution:

```
QString l_str = "Ho€ Ar€ you?";
qDebug() << "hex:     " << l_str.toUtf8().toHex();
qDebug() << "readable:" << l_str.toUtf8();

QTextCodec* l_codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-16");

QByteArray l_string = l_codec->fromUnicode(l_str).toHex();
qDebug() << "utf16 encoded: " << l_string;

QByteArray l_reversed;

for(int i=0; i < l_string.length(); i=i+4)
{
    QString l_hex_chars_1 = l_string.mid(i, 2);
    QString l_hex_chars_2 = l_string.mid(i+2, 2);
    l_reversed.append(l_hex_chars_2);
    l_reversed.append(l_hex_chars_1);
}

QByteArray l_bom("feff");
if(l_reversed.startsWith(l_bom))
{
    l_reversed.remove(0, l_bom.length());
}

QString l_res;

for(int i=0; i < l_reversed.length(); i=i+4)
{
    QString l_hex_chars_1 = l_reversed.mid(i, 2);
    QString l_hex_chars_2 = l_reversed.mid(i+2, 2);

    int l_val = l_hex_chars_1.toInt(0,16)*256+l_hex_chars_2.toInt(0,16);
    QChar l_char(l_val);
    l_res.append(l_char);
}
qDebug() << "back to string: " << l_res;
```

This prints out:

> hex:      "48e282ac77206172e282ac20796f753f"
>
> readable: "H€w ar€ you?"
>
> utf16 encoded:  "fffe4800ac207700200061007200ac20200079006f0075003f00"
>
> byte-reversed:  "004820ac007700200061007220ac00200079006f0075003f"
>
> back to string:  "H€w ar€ you?"

Comment: The utf16 byte order mark is there so that the decoder can do byte-swapping if necessary. You aren't supposed to be swapping anything yourself. You also don't need to construct a codec to get a utf-16 representation of a string: you get one using `QString::utf16()`. You can prepend a `QChar::ByteOrderMark` to it manually.